# How do I get information about an instance of a delegate function (like name or containing class) in C#?

Tags: c#, delegates

I have a delegate function

```
class FuncActivator {
  public delegate void DelFunc(string arg, string val);
}
```

I keep instances of that function to start at the same time later within the program (Also in `FuncActivator`:

```
List<DelFunc> funcList = new List<DelFunc>();

public void KeepFunc(DelFunc delFunc) {
  funcList.Add(delFunc);
}
```

Now I want to get information about the actual delegate name, or it least which class passed it here. For example, in a different class

```
public class FunnyClass {
  public void FunnyFunc(string arg, string val) {
    //..Do stuff
  }

  public FunnyClass () {
    FuncActivatorInstance.KeepFunc(FunnyFunc);
  }
}
```

I'd like from a method within `FuncActivator` to list the names or callers of all the delegates in my list (like "FunnyFunc" or at least "FunnyClass").
Is that possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code:

```
public void PrintFuncs()
{
    foreach (var func in funcList)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(func.Method.Name);
        Console.WriteLine(func.Method.DeclaringType.Name);
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
FunnyFunc
FunnyClass
```

The instance of `FunnyClass` that added itself to the list is at `func.Target`, if you'd like to use that, too.

Lambdas that are attached, since they are anonymous, will have an auto-generated method name.  If a class was generated for it as well, it will have an auto-generated name as well.  So just FYI, you won't always be able to have very readable strings from this.

Comment: Well thanks :) That worked perfectly even though my editor didn't auto complete the Method member and its members.